# How to get the keyboard for email addresses in my app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an EditText in my app and it's set to

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

but it comes up as the default keyboard instead of this one with the "@" and ".com" buttons: [image: this]

Is there a specific line of code to get it to show up???

Comment: That is the correct `inputType` - something else is going wrong in your code. Perhaps you could post your XML and a code snippit for where you're initializing the EditText.

Comment: @BrianRoach Ok, here's the XML for the EditText:


    **<EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="190dp"></EditText>**


I don't really have any Java specific for this button. Just the basic code for the Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'android:inputType' is merely a hint for your IME. Check [this](http://s482.codeinspot.com/q/1779389) post.

Hope this would answer your question.